# How to search for a specific file name with unknown path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a small program for my work that will work over a network and some specified drives. I'm new to python 3 (and python) so please bear with me pls. This program links or finds a small unique number in case the file has been moved to another location. Can anyone give me an example (or where to find one) of a code that searches for a file name within specified range of folders and then returns the file location. This would be helpful if it wasn't meant for current directory finding (as that is all the examples I've seen so far). Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I think what you are after is [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: So far I've used os.environ, findInSubdirectory, search_file, os.path.abspath. I think it is more of my fault not properly defining areas of the code as I can't get the program to print the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

something like this maybe

```
def findfile(fname,base_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
        if fname in files:
            return os.path.join(root,fname)

    return None
```

Comment: `os.walk` will do the recursion for you, so the `for dir in dirs` loop can be omitted. (Otherwise, +1)

Comment: oops right you are ... wasnt thinking good catch :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just don't know what to define root to. It's giving me an error.

Comment: when trying to print that is

Comment: Stupid question how would i get the program to print out the location?

Comment: Think I found an example. Gonna give it a try. Thanks for all the help!